# In a MySQL SELECT query, can I use my "AS column" in a WHERE specification?

Tags: mysql

In my database I calculate distance between nodes with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       dest.name,
       AsText(orig.location),
       AsText(dest.location),
       round((glength(linestringfromwkb(linestring((orig.location), (dest.location)))))) as distance
FROM nodes orig,
     nodes dest
WHERE orig.name='GERP'
```

I would like to add

```
and distance < dest.visibility
```

at the end, but am told that distance is an unknown column.

Any insight very much appreciated.

Comment: You could use the alias in a HAVING clause, but that'd be highly inefficient for a field such as this, with a large computational overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       dest.name,
       AsText(orig.location),
       AsText(dest.location),
       round((glength(linestringfromwkb(linestring((orig.location), (dest.location)))))) as distance
  FROM nodes orig,
       nodes dest
 WHERE orig.name = 'GERP'
   AND round((glength(linestringfromwkb(linestring((orig.location), (dest.location)))))) < dest.visibility
```

SQL doesn't allow accessing column aliases in the WHERE clause -- the earliest MySQL supports is the `GROUP BY` clause.

Also, your query lacks criteria to join the two table instances -- resulting in a cartesian product.

Comment: Thank you - this is what I am going with!

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery, then you only have to type the formula in once (and if you need to change it, you only need to change it once).

```
SELECT
       dest.name,
       dest.visibility,
       AsText(orig.location),
       AsText(dest.location),
       distance
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT
       dest.name,
       dest.visibility,
       AsText(orig.location),
       AsText(dest.location),
       round((glength(linestringfromwkb(linestring((orig.location), (dest.location)))))) as distance
FROM nodes orig,
     nodes dest
WHERE orig.name='GERP'
) AS nodeDistances
WHERE nodeDistainces.distance < visibility
```

Comment: The subquery is unnecessary -- this approach risks two passes over the table, not good for performance.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can add

```
and dest.visibility > round((glength(linestringfromwkb(linestring((orig.location), (dest.location))))))
```

mysql should be smart enough to only compute the expression once.

Answer (score 1):

HAVING is your friend.

> A select_expr can be given an alias
>   using AS alias_name. The alias is used
>   as the expression's column name and
>   can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or
>   HAVING clauses.
>
> To accommodate both standard SQL and
>   the MySQL-specific behavior of being
>   able to refer columns in the SELECT
>   list, MySQL 5.0.2 and up permit HAVING
>   to refer to columns in the SELECT
>   list, columns in the GROUP BY clause,
>   columns in outer subqueries, and to
>   aggregate functions.

Note that HAVING can't be optimized and will be dog slow. Not a new problem with your query, though...

Comment: "Not a new problem with your query, though...". Love it ;-) +1

Comment: The HAVING clause is for aggregate usage, not relying on MySQL's functionality that few if any other databases support.

Comment: of course, it's MySQL specific sorry if that was not clear enough. The question is about MysQL specific, too and so is there query in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the result set calculated column name in the where clause.

You need to (sadly) re-use the whole expression you used to calculate it

```
and round((glength(linestringfromwkb(linestring((orig.location), (dest.location))))))
    < dest.visibility
```

There are two work-arounds:

1. If you create the text of the query outside of SQL (e.g. from Perl, PHP etc...), you can store the expression in a string before the query and re-use the string:

   ```
   $long_expr = "round((glength(linestringfromwkb(linestring((orig.location), (dest.location))))))";
   $sql = qq[SELECT DISTINCT
   ```

   dest.name,
      AsText(orig.location),
      AsText(dest.location),
      $long_expr as distance
      ...
      and $long_expr < dest.visibility
2. Store the original query (sans the last AND) in a temp table (but inlcude `visibility` column in the select), and then do the following

   ```
   SELECT * from #temp_table
   WHERE distance < visibility
   ```
3. Same as #2, but instead of temp table, do a subquery.